# Add custom field to Attribute page in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to add 1 custom field like 'image'
in that image Image link and upload option field should come.
See example:-I have added in category image field
I have created GENERAL tab in that option to upload image.

[image]

likewise i want to add in attribute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to add No5 Image and its Link on the same page?

Comment: no no @MTM. I Have 1 attribute called "Back to school" Edit Product Attribute "Back to School" i want to add 1 tab to image upload like above question.